# Function Returning Different Results with Same Inputs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a modeling function to model the motion of a train. In my script, I have a check that runs a function three times. The second and third time it returns the same values, however on the first time, it returns different values.

```
    dvdtA = lambda x, v: (1 / (Tmass + mw)) * (Ap * (rg / rw)) * (((P0gauge + Patm) * V0) / (V0 + (Ap * (rg / rw) * x)) - Patm) \
        -0.5 * Cd * pa * A * (v**2) - (Cr * Tmass * g)

    dvdtD = lambda v: (1 / Tmass) * (- 0.5 * Cd * pa * A * (v**2) - (Cr * Tmass * g))
    dxdt = lambda v: v
    Ft = lambda x: (1 / (Tmass + mw)) * (Ap * (rg / rw)) * (((P0gauge + Patm) * V0) / (V0 + (Ap * (rg / rw) * x)) - Patm)
    trainMotion = np.array([dvdtA, dvdtD, dxdt, Ft])

    # Checking design constraints ######################################
    if (Ht < 0.23) and (Wt < 0.2) and (rg/rw < 1):

        # Optimization #################################################
        if RK4(trainMotion, h, tspan, v0, x0, La, slipCheck) is not None:
            if RK4(trainMotion, h, tspan, v0, x0, La, slipCheck)[1] < tFinish:
                bestParams = np.array([r0, P0gauge, rg, Ls, rp, tankMat])
                bestODE = trainMotion
                bestLa = La
                bestSlipCheck = slipCheck
                bestTime = RK4(trainMotion, h, tspan, v0, x0, La, slipCheck)[1]
```

This is written inside a for loop that randomly selects a set of parameters then runs them through to generate the ODES you see at the beginning. The error is happening underneath the "Optimization" area. The first call on RK4 generates a different set of results than the second and third, which both generate the exact same results. I can't figure out why the first time is different than the second and third.
Furthermore, when I plug those "best[ODE/LA/etc] into the RK4 function again later on in the script, it fails the checks and returns None despite those parameters having passed the checks earlier.

For reference, here's the RK4 function itself:

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np

def RungeKutta(fun, h, tspan, x0, y0, Ls, slipCheck):
    yArr = np.zeros([len(tspan), 2])
    yArr[0,1] = y0
    yArr[0,0] = x0
    
    for i in range(len(tspan) - 1):
        
        k1 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1])
        k2 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1] + k1 * (h/2))
        k3 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1] + k2 * (h/2))
        k4 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1] + k3 * h)

        yArr[i+1, 0] = yArr[i, 0] + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)
        
        if (fun[3](yArr[i+1, 0]) > slipCheck) or (yArr[i+1, 0] > 12.5):
            return None

        if yArr[i, 0] <= Ls:
            k1 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0], yArr[i, 1])
            k2 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0] + h/2, yArr[i, 1] + k1 * (h/2))
            k3 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0] + h/2, yArr[i, 1] + k2 * (h/2))
            k4 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0] + h, yArr[i, 1] + k3 * h)

            yArr[i+1, 1] = yArr[i, 1] + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

        elif yArr[i, 0] > Ls:
            k1 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1])
            k2 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1] + k1 * (h/2))
            k3 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1] + k2 * (h/2))
            k4 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1] + k3 * h)
                   
            yArr[i+1, 1] = yArr[i, 1] + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

        if i >= 3:
            if yArr[i+1, 1] < 0 and yArr[i+1, 0] > 10:
                tFinish = tspan[i]
                data = np.column_stack((yArr, tspan))
                return data, tFinish       

    return None
```

Comment: Why calculate it 3 times (not really optimal), calculate it once and use the result 3 times, why don't you return `(None.None)`, RK4 returns always 2 items, otherwise `return np.column_stack((yArr, tspan)), tspan[i]`

Comment: instead of all the divide `/`, transform it to `*` that is way faster, at least in C++, maybe the python statement execution is slow compared to `/`

Comment: have you dumped the intermediate results `yArr` for each run and compare where they differ and then find out why

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are re-creating the lambda statements in each iteration? This kind of thing is very hard to debug. I would recoment to `def` the functions with according arguments before the loop to avoid unintentional change of variables by the optimization, which could be the case for mutuable data-structures.

Comment: The lambda statements are recreated in each iteration of the for loop, but the three times the function is called here, it uses the lambda functions without rewriting them. @JonathanWeine

Comment: That solution would actually bypass the problem altogether, thanks! 
I wanted to do the call just once and use the results but I couldn’t figure how to do the none check. While accomplishing that. @rioV8

Comment: I ended up changing how I wrote that segment -ironically it ended up doing 4 calls of the function- but it’s getting the same results with each call, and I still couldn’t figure why it’s doing it on this version. @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

Let RK4 always return 2 values, unpack the values when calling RK4

```
    dvdtA = lambda x, v: (1 / (Tmass + mw)) * (Ap * (rg / rw)) * (((P0gauge + Patm) * V0) / (V0 + (Ap * (rg / rw) * x)) - Patm) \
        -0.5 * Cd * pa * A * (v**2) - (Cr * Tmass * g)

    dvdtD = lambda v: (1 / Tmass) * (- 0.5 * Cd * pa * A * (v**2) - (Cr * Tmass * g))
    dxdt = lambda v: v
    Ft = lambda x: (1 / (Tmass + mw)) * (Ap * (rg / rw)) * (((P0gauge + Patm) * V0) / (V0 + (Ap * (rg / rw) * x)) - Patm)
    trainMotion = np.array([dvdtA, dvdtD, dxdt, Ft])

    # Checking design constraints ######################################
    if (Ht < 0.23) and (Wt < 0.2) and (rg/rw < 1):

        # Optimization #################################################
        data, tFinishResult = RK4(trainMotion, h, tspan, v0, x0, La, slipCheck)
        if data is not None:
            if tFinishResult < tFinish:
                bestParams = np.array([r0, P0gauge, rg, Ls, rp, tankMat])
                bestODE = trainMotion
                bestLa = La
                bestSlipCheck = slipCheck
                bestTime = tFinishResult
```

The RK4 function:

```
import math as mt
import numpy as np

def RungeKutta(fun, h, tspan, x0, y0, Ls, slipCheck):
    yArr = np.zeros([len(tspan), 2])
    yArr[0,1] = y0
    yArr[0,0] = x0
    
    for i in range(len(tspan) - 1):
        
        k1 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1])
        k2 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1] + k1 * (h/2))
        k3 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1] + k2 * (h/2))
        k4 = fun[2](yArr[i, 1] + k3 * h)

        yArr[i+1, 0] = yArr[i, 0] + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)
        
        if (fun[3](yArr[i+1, 0]) > slipCheck) or (yArr[i+1, 0] > 12.5):
            return None,None

        if yArr[i, 0] <= Ls:
            k1 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0], yArr[i, 1])
            k2 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0] + h/2, yArr[i, 1] + k1 * (h/2))
            k3 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0] + h/2, yArr[i, 1] + k2 * (h/2))
            k4 = fun[0](yArr[i, 0] + h, yArr[i, 1] + k3 * h)

            yArr[i+1, 1] = yArr[i, 1] + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

        elif yArr[i, 0] > Ls:
            k1 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1])
            k2 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1] + k1 * (h/2))
            k3 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1] + k2 * (h/2))
            k4 = fun[1](yArr[i, 1] + k3 * h)
                   
            yArr[i+1, 1] = yArr[i, 1] + h * (k1/6 + k2/3 + k3/3 + k4/6)

        if i >= 3:
            if yArr[i+1, 1] < 0 and yArr[i+1, 0] > 10:
                data = np.column_stack((yArr, tspan))
                tFinish = tspan[i]
                return data, tFinish       

    return None, None
```